# PHP: Week starts on Monday, but "monday this week" on a Sunday gets Monday next week

Tags: php, datetime

Here's a summary of the issue: On Sundays, `strtotime('this week')` returns the start of next week.

In PHP, the week seems to start on Monday. But, on any day except Sunday, this code

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('monday this week', strtotime('last sunday')));
```

Outputs the date of this week's Monday, when it seems like it should be outputting last weeks Monday. It seems like, in this case, PHP is treating both Sunday and Monday as the the start of the week. It's now Monday, Dec 10, 2012, or 2012-12-10. `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('sunday last week'))` returns `2012-12-09` - yesterday.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something? It seems like a bug this obvious should be fairly well known, but I can't find anything about it. Is the only way to get the start of the week to use some special handling for Sundays?

```
$week_offset = (int) 'sunday' == date('l');
$week_start  = strtotime("-$week_offset monday"); // 1 or 0 Mondays ago
```

Comment: Perhaps there are timezone shenanigans afoot?  Can you try this with a [DateTime](http://php.net/class.datetime) that's been tied to a local [DateTimeZone](http://php.net/class.datetimezone)?  Also, have you replaced your server's flux capacitor?  They wear out after a while.  :p

Comment: I think first day of week for PHP date function is Sunday: _w | Numeric representation of the day of the week | 0 (for Sunday) through 6 (for Saturday)_

Comment: @SalmanA, I thought that too, but I kept noticing as I was working on the site that getting the start of the week returned Monday. For instance, `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('this week');` returns Monday's date.
And the capital W under the week section of the $format parameter says the week starts on Monday:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

_italic_W | ISO-8601 week number of year, weeks starting on Monday (added in PHP 4.1.0)_italic_
I haven't been able to find any statement to prove for certain that PHP's weeks start on Monday except for unsubstantiated claims in forum and blog posts.

Comment: @Charles, I tried this and got the same result:
`$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
$date->setTimestamp(strtotime('last sunday'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');`

Also, I checked, and the quasitronic fluxication rate on my server should be... unlimited. So, I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: You might want to chech [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376484/issue-with-getting-week-starting-from-sunday) out too.

Comment: I've posted a bug report here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63740 Feel free to add your feedback.

Comment: That's an excellent bug report. Thanks, Salman. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is a bug. I see no logical reason why `strtotime('this week');` should return a future date. This is a pretty major bug. In my particular case, I had a leaderboard that showed the users with the most points since the beginning of the week. But on Sundays, it was empty because `strtotime` returned a timestamp for a future date. I was doubtful, because just I don't know how this could have gone unnoticed, but I couldn't find any other reports of this bug.

Thanks for all your time and help, folks.

Comment: A little bit late, I had the same problem... You can simply fix this by doing `strtotime('next Monday -1 week');` This will always give you the Monday of the current week ;)

Comment: @FrederikVoordeckers great idea! Didn't work for me like that but this did: `$this_date_start = new DateTime('next monday'); $this_date_start ->sub(new DateInterval('P7D'));`

Comment: This works great @FrederikVoordeckers. But on sunday I must use `strtotime('sunday this week')`.

Answer (score 7):

This answer is late, but it's something that I've been struggling with.  Every solution I've tried so far has malfunctioned for one reason or another.   This is what I ended up with that worked for me.  (though it may be look pretty, it at least works).

```
$thisMonday =  strtotime('next Monday -1 week', strtotime('this sunday'));
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is how you can get Monday of current week:

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date('o-\\WW')));
```

Comment: On a Monday that will return the date of last week's Monday.
`echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('o-\\WW'), strtotime('2013-02-18')));`
`2013-02-18` is a Monday. The above code echos `2013-02-11`, which is the previous Monday. Regardless, it doesn't explain why PHP should return a date in the future when I supply "this week" to `strtotime`

Comment: I've just used this solution and strtotime(date('o-\\WW')) returns the same monday if the base timestamp is a monday too. Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @turibe, your strtotime is in the wrong place, it should be: ```echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('o-\\WW', strtotime('2013-02-18'))));```

Answer (score 3):

It's not ideal but this is what I resorted to using:

```
if(date('N') == 7) { 
    $date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('monday last week'));
} else {
    $date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('monday this week'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of trying

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('monday this week', strtotime('last sunday')));
```

you should try

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('monday last week'));
```

Comment: That would work if I was trying to get the date of last Monday, but what I'm trying to do is get the date of the most recent Monday, including today if today is Monday. `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('this week');` returns Monday's date, regardless of what day you run that code on or supply as `strtotime`'s second parameter.

Comment: Which is to say I  want to get the start of the week. But if I make the attempt to get the start of the week during a Sunday, PHP returns a date in the future: The coming Monday.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
// set current date
$date = date("m/d/Y");
$ts = strtotime($date); // also $ts = time();

// find the year and the current week
$year = date('o', $ts);
$week = date('W', $ts);
// print week for the current date
$i = 1; // 1 denotes the first day of week

$ts = strtotime($year.'W'.$week.$i);
echo $day = date("l", $ts); // generate the name of day
echo "<br>";
echo $day = date("Y-m-d", $ts); // generate the date
```

You will get the the date of current week, whether you are on monday you will get the date of that monday.

Comment: I showed how to get that in my question too, but for semi-academic purposes I want to know if this is a bug, or if there's a valid reason for PHP's behavior. I can't understand what that would be. If it's a bug, I need to report it. But it seems crazy that a bug this major would not have been reported yet.

Comment: @turibe As stated before, this is not a bug. PHP considers Monday the start of the week, if you choose to use `word type` phrases. If you want it to use Sunday as start of the week, the you need to do some workarounds.

Comment: @DainisAbols I know that PHP considers Monday the start of the week. I don't want to use Sunday as the start of the week.
On Sundays, `strtotime('this week')` returns next week. That seems like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the most recent monday:

```
function mostRecentMonday(){
  if(date("w") == 1){
   return strtotime("midnight today");
  } else {
   return strtotime("last monday");
  }
}
```

Easy to modify to use DateTime, or, to even specify a different date to use as the base.

Comment: You should use `strototime('midnight today')` instead of `time()` for consistency, as `last monday` returns midnight on that day.

Comment: @antriver agreed. I updated my comment to reflect your suggestion. The original example wasn't dealing with the time component (just Y-m-d) so it wouldn't really matter, but it's always good to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

```
  I think the only problem with your coding is TimeZone.
```

**Solution:**
          Set your own time Zone. Here is the example of my own time zone:

**Example**

```
   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');


   Set the above line before calling any time function.
```

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Bryant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32584683/7917266) answer :

```
$first_week_date = date('d F Y', strtotime('next Monday -1 week', strtotime('this sunday')));
$last_week_date = date('d F Y', strtotime('next Monday -1 week + 6 days', strtotime('this sunday')));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for thos looking for a friendly solution that works with any day.

```
function getWeekStart($week_start_day = "Monday") {
    $week_days = array("Sunday"=>0,"Monday"=>1,"Tuesday"=>2,"Wednesday"=>3,"Thursday"=>4,"Friday"=>5,"Saturday"=>6,);

    if(!isset($week_days[$week_start_day])) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $start_day = $week_days[$week_start_day];

        $today = date("w");
        $one_day = (60 * 60 * 24);

        if($today < $start_day) {
            $days_difference = 7 - ($start_day - $today);
        } else {
            $days_difference = ($today - $start_day);
        }

        $week_starts = strtotime(date("Y-m-d 00:00:00")) - ($one_day * $days_difference);

        return $week_starts;
    }
}

//Test: If today is Monday, it will return today's date
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", getWeekStart("Monday"));
```