# How can I make date("W") start in Sunday and end on saturday?

Tags: php, date

PHP documentation says `date("W")` starts in Monday and ends in sunday, is there any way to change it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057039/how-to-get-weeks-starting-on-sunday